# 'Import' in typescript files in a Blazor WebAssembly apparently doesn't work

Tags: typescript, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application, where I use an external JavaScript library (fabric.js) and I needed to write some client code to customize that behaviour.

I wrote a few classes in TypeScript, but I couldn't make them work when in separate files (**while they work perfectly when all in the same file**).

Problems arise when I try to import a class from a different file:

```
import { SomeClass } from './ts/somefile';
```

Apparently the runtime cannot handle this request, that by the way **works perfectly in tests** (I created a simple Node.js application just for the tests, and they work perfectly).

So my point is: what is missing (that I can add) to a 'standard' Blazor WebAssembly project, to have the runtime manage correctly JavaScript dependencies, if possible at all? Or the fact that it's not a traditional 'server' application prevents it to support this scenario?

Thanks.

P.S.: for completeness, I load the file in the Blazor application with:

```
    _module = await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", $"./ts/MyMainClass.js");
```

Comment: You are talking about two different things here. Blazor has nothing to do with Typescript. Typescript is used to generate js files that are then executed in a javascript environment like a browser or node.js. So, if it doesn't work without Blazor, it wouldn't work with it.  The InvokeAsync calls an existing javascript function. While ``import`` is a valid js function, it can be used outside a module. So, use the tsconfig.json to let typescript create a single file from all ts files, include this in ``index.html``, and call the function from JsInterop.

Comment: If you want to have a brief example, let me know, and I'll write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `.js` (not `.ts`) extension to the import line:

```
import { SomeClass } from './ts/somefile.js';
```

I had a similar problem and where the import from the .razor file works fine but then if there are imports within the TypeScript file the import failed with the message `failed to fetch dynamically imported module`.

This problem is not unique to TypeScript and also happens with plain JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I see it only now. I solve my problem, at the time, in another way, but I think your answer is correct, so I will mark it as the answer, for other people coming here... Thank you.